# How is the default launcher set after a factory reset

Tags: recovery-mode, launcher, default-applications, system-apps, rom-update

I would like to know how is the default launcher set after a factory reset. What files are in charge of telling the OS, for example, that the Touchwiz app is the default launcher for Samsung devices.

I do not want to replace the launcher, that is something I already know how to do. This is a very specific question regarding how the os works. I am interested in doing a system update via recovery and changing the files that tell the OS which app is the default launcher, in order to tell it that my newly flashed app (flashed in system partition) is.

I look forward to your response. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

As stated, Samsung is just a given example but it is one of an endless list. This is an os general-behaviour related question not manufacturer specific.

Comment: Umm, most cases there's only one launcher so it's naturally set as default?

Comment: @AndyYan OP is talking Samsung. They often duplicate things. Wouldn't wonder if they had the stock (AOSP) launcher as well, while making their TouchWiz one the default. I vaguely remember having seen that on a device: installed *Apex* and of course got asked to chose – but out of 3 instead of 2 launchers (AOSP, manufacturers, Apex). Apex was the only user-installed launcher; still, no choice had to be made before installing it.

Comment: I don't believe there's ever any AOSP launcher built into Sammy devices I owned, but now that you mentioned it, I do remember there's a "Simple Home" or something named like that which is a very simplistic launcher for grannies and such.

Answer (score 1):

If a ROM has multiple launchers, and one is not set by default in the default factory configuration, then after the Setup Wizard completes and the device attempts to go to the desktop, a pop-up appears asking you to select the Home application and it will give you an option to "Always do this".

You can select a launcher here, but until you select "Always do this" (or similar text) this pop-up selection window will appear every time the Home button is pressed.

This is common in custom ROMs which have multiple launchers pre-installed.

Comment: when you say "and one is not set by default in the default factory configuration"  you mean that it actually can be configured. What files do I need to set a particular factory configuration? Do you know?

Comment: @Storo I don't know that, that is outside of the scope of Android Enthusiasts as it is a question regarding development. It is possible though, as Samsungs do not do that, although most custom ROMs with more than one launcher pre-loaded force you to manually make a selection.

Comment: @Storo if that is the thing than yes but you will have to unpack file where settings are saved

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Great, I have no problem in doing that, I am just asking which are the files in the /system partition or whatever where I have to modify.